# How can multiple users send emails with Gmail alias in Node.js without user authentication from Google developer Console for each user?

Tags: node.js, email, authentication, gmail, google-api-nodejs-client

I tried for allowing the less secure app. In that, emails are sent from one original authenticated user.
Also, I implemented the method of Authentication with OAuth2 by authenticating from google developer console with Gmail API, Using Client ID, Client Secret Key, Refresh Token, Access Token, still it was sending emails from the authenticated user only not from any other Gmail alias.
Basically, I am trying to create a mail service in node js, where each new user will use his "from" Gmail alias to send emails.

Kindly, tell me how I can set up a mailing API in node js in which each user can send email from his Gmail alias to the recipients.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

- Using a [3-legged OAuth flow](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client) where users log in, pass refresh/access tokens back to your app which you store, then use to send emails.  This is a good model to use if your users interact with your app via a web page, and if the users can come from any Google account.
- Using a 2-legged OAuth flow with domain wide delegation enabled - this is a good model to use if everyone is on one gsuite domain, and you have [domain wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7223765?hl=en) enabled.

If you want to share some more details on which of these makes the most sense, I'm happy to point you at the right docs :)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I want to use a 3-legged OAuth flow. For it I have created a project in the google developer console and have got the JSON file but do not know how to implement it so that any Gmail user come and authenticate and authorize it to our web app..

Comment: Sure!  Follow this guide: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client